# Solr indexing parquet file

Tags: indexing, solr, parquet

I have a solr instance up and running and it should read parquet files to index. Right now, I am converting the parquet to flat text file and then having solr index them. I'd like to know if it is possible to read the parquet file directly for Solr to consume?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly: no, not possible.

If you want something more integrated than what you are actually doing (converting to text and indexing might be good enough already), you can follow two ways:

1. Create an specialized code around DIH, you probably can write a specialized [DataSource](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#DataSource), so you could use DIH to do the indexing.
2. Just write some java code using SolrJ that reads your file and indexes to Solr

Comment: Thank you, Persi. I was hoping for a more straight forward approach. But, this approach could be a way to go. I'll look into that.